# If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are path connected covering spaces of $X$ then prove that in the following case $f:T_1\to T_2$ is surjective.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p_1 :T_1 \to X$ and $p_2 :T_2 \to X$ be covering. $T_1, T_2$ are path connected spaces, $f : T_1 \to T_2$ is a continuous map, and $p_1=p_2 f$.
Please prove $f$ is surjective.

Note:This is an exercise about covering space, the reason make me confused is we only know the definition of covering space and homotopy lift property,  another conception such coverings and their fundamental group, monodromy action we have not learn now. So from author's view, only using definition of covering space can solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't show too much effort to prove it yourself, I'll only give you a

**Hint:**

By pathconnectedness: for every $x\in T_2$ there is a path from the base point to $x$. Push this down to a path in $X$, as you know this will lift to $T_1$. What do we know about its image under $T_1\to T_2$?